# Sum the occurence of the string in the JSON array and store it in separate JSON array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON array as follows:

```
var teamDetails=[ 
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 5},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Business", "value" : 1,},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Internet Services", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 6},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1} 
];
```

*I want to take the count of the ptype dynamically and individually and should be applied if there is a change in ptype.*

**`Expected output:`**

```
var output = [{"label":"Search Engines"},{"Occurance":4},{"label":"Content Server"},{"Occurance":3},{"label":"Business"},{"Occurance":1},{"label":"Internet Services"},{"Occurance":1}];
```

Comment: what have you already try  ? add some  code please

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce` and then `map` methods to first create object to groupBy and then get an array of objects.

```js
var data=[ { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 5},{ "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},{ "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},{ "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1},{ "pType" : "Business", "value" : 1,},{ "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},{ "pType" : "Internet Services", "value" : 1},{ "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 6},{ "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1} ];

const obj = data.reduce((r, {pType: label, Occurance}) => {
  if(!r[label]) r[label] = {label, Occurance: 1}
  else r[label].Occurance++;
  return r;
}, {})

const result = [].concat(...Object.values(obj).map(({label, Occurance}) => [{label}, {Occurance}])) 
  
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the array and use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for keeping track of the counts, later give it the wanted style.

```js
var teamDetails = [{ pType: "Search Engines", value: 5 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 1 }, { pType: "Business", value: 1 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Internet Services", value: 1 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 6 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 1 }];
    output = [];

teamDetails
    .reduce((m, { pType }) => m.set(pType, (m.get(pType) || 0) + 1), new Map)
    .forEach((Occurance, label) => output.push({ label }, { Occurance }));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurrences of each `pType` using the `array#reduce` and then using `array#reduce` and `Object.entries` create the output.

```js
var teamDetails=[ { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 5}, { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1}, { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1}, { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1}, { "pType" : "Business", "value" : 1,}, { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1}, { "pType" : "Internet Services", "value" : 1}, { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 6}, { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1} ],
    result = Object.entries(teamDetails.reduce((r, {pType}) => {
      r[pType] = (r[pType] || 0) + 1;
      return r;
    },{}))
    .reduce((r,[label,Occurance]) => {
      r.push({label},{Occurance});
      return r;
    }, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```js
var teamDetails= [ 
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 5},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Business", "value" : 1,},
 { "pType" : "Content Server", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Internet Services", "value" : 1},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 6},
 { "pType" : "Search Engines", "value" : 1} 
];

const temp = teamDetails.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.pType] ? acc[item.pType]++ : acc[item.pType] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const res = Object.keys(temp).reduce((acc, key) => {
  acc.push({ label: key });
  acc.push({ Occurence: temp[key] })
  return acc;
},[]);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.etries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) like this:

Get the count of each `pType` as a key-value pair using the first `reduce` -> Then use `Object.entries` to get each key-value as an array -> Use the second `reduce` to get the final desired array.

```js
const teamDetails = [{ pType: "Search Engines", value: 5 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 1 }, { pType: "Business", value: 1 }, { pType: "Content Server", value: 1 }, { pType: "Internet Services", value: 1 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 6 }, { pType: "Search Engines", value: 1 }]
  
const count = Object.entries(teamDetails.reduce((a, {pType}) =>
        (a[pType] = a[pType] + 1 || 1, a), {}))
    .reduce((a, [k, v]) =>
        (a.push({label: k}, { Occurance: v }), a), [])
        
console.log(count)
```